# Rotate line with two points

Tags: vector, rotation, geometry, plane

I have line with two points

```
(x1, y1) (x2, y2)
```

and I am working on x+, y+ plane only

and say this line is vertical say

```
(320, 320) (320, 160)
```

How do I rotate it by 90 degrees to get

```
(320, 320) (480, 320)  [90 deg rotated by bottom point (320, 320)]
(320, 160) (480, 160)  [90 deg rotated by top point (320, 160)]
```

Remember I would need in same form—i.e,

```
(x1, y1) (x2, y2)
```

By the way, these lines can only be vertical or horizontal, so the slope is either undefined or zero.

Comment: oh by the way these lines can only be vertical or horizontal so slope is either undefined or zero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rotate `B` 90 degrees around `A`:

```
diff = B-A
B_new = A + array([-diff[1],diff[0]])
```

To be more general, you do this:

```
def rot_origin(p, ang):
    return array([p[0]*cos(ang)-p[1]*sin(ang),p[0]*sin(ang)+p[1]*cos(ang)])

def rot_around(p, p0, ang):
    return p0 + rot_origin(p-p0, ang)
```

Then, your case would be `B_new = rot_around(A, B, pi/2)`, since `90` degrees is `pi/2` radians.

Edit: Just to make it completely explicit for your example. To rotate by 90 degrees around point 1, you would get:

```
(x1,y1) (x1-(y2-y1),y1+(x2-x1))
```

To rotate around point 2, you would get:

```
(x2-(y1-y2),y2+(x1-x2)) (x2,y2)
```

Comment: Hello, I have a question. What does p and p0 represent when you substract them? as well as with B-A?

Answer (score -1):

To get what you put as example:

1. Get the distance between top and bottom points. In your example, d = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2).
2. For a 90 degrees rotation by bottom point, simply use (x2,y2) and (x2+d, y2) as end points.
3. For a 90 degrees rotation by top point, simply use (x1,y1) and (x1+d, y1) as end points.

This can be easily generalized to any line, not only a vertical one, and any rotation angle.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? If my points are (0,0) (1,0), then according to you, the result will be (0,0) (1,0) or (1,0) (2,0). Neither of those can be interpreted as a rotation by 90 degrees.

Comment: @amaurea If your points are (0,0) (1,0), it is not a vertical line, but an horizontal line. I was giving a response for the example, not a general one, that would involve the use of the rotation matrix, as you correctly do in your response.